# find and replace only first match in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Anyone know how to replace only the first match instead of all in perl. If I use without /g it replacing all.

```
$string =~ s/regex/replacement/;
```

Comment: That replaces only the first match. Please show an example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. If you **use** with the `g` flag it **will** replace all. Otherwise, only first match.

Comment: `s/search/replace/` only replace the first match. For more you can show us your code what are you trying.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'foo bar baz foo foo bar';
my $replace = 'bar';

$string =~ s/$replace/REPLACEMENT/;

print "$string\n";
```

Or use `\Q` to automatically escape non word characters:

```
$string =~ s/\Q$replace/REPLACEMENT/;
```